# Which entries in my list do not have an entry in my table?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I do something like this in MySQL?

```
 (1274649,682844,872502,1016256) 
 INTERSECT 
 (SELECT id  FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN (1274649,682844,872502,1016256))
```

---

*Adapting from the comments:*

> These four numbers are the IDs that I have now.  I want to know which of these IDs do not have an an entry in my table, and how many of them don't have an entry?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit? where are you getting those numbers from? why not just intersect those 2 number sets beforehand? and why are you selecting the `id` using the `id`?

Comment: This does not seem consistent with the mathematical definition of intersection.  Can you explain?

Comment: these are the id's  that i have now i want to know how many of them dont have a entry in my table

Comment: Just do `SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN (...)` then check which ids in the `...` aren't returned.

Comment: i dont wnat to manually verify cany i do in some query

Comment: The INTERSECT of those two lists is the same as the result of the SELECT statement, so you don't need to do the INTERSECT part of the operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.id from (
    select 1274649 as id union
    select 682844 union
    select 872502 union
    select 1016256
) t
left join users u on u.id = t.id
where u.id is null
```

This returns those `id`s that haven't corresponding `id` in `users` table.

**Added** this is the answer to OP explanation in comment: [Which entries in my list do not have an entry in my table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527940/which-entries-in-my-list-do-not-have-an-entry-in-my-table/10528550#comment13617653_10527940)

Comment: Your query does `<list> MINUS <select>` rather than `<list> INTERSECT <select>`, doesn't it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, you are right but this is an answer to [OP explanation in comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527940/doing-a-intersect-with-my-data/10528550#comment13617653_10527940) - will show which of them don't have entry in `users` table.

Comment: I see - yes; the question is couched in the incorrect terms and needs to be updated, title, example, and all.  What you've got provides what the comment requests.